# vscode wont install extension in containers

Tags: visual-studio-code, containers

I am using vscode (version 1.74.2) docker extension to attach it to docker containers. When the UI opens a new window, it requires me to install extensions in the container as well.
[image]
However clicking on the "install in container" does nothing, is there a way to do this via command line to see if i get any logs?

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting).